# Random number generation and plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, plot

I've written a code to generate 10 random numbers (tags) and display them on a plot with their co-ordinates shown. These random numbers are fixed. I've added 3 red points (readers) to the code that should also be generated randomly but not be fixed. When I added the code to fix the tags the readers became fixed also, I'd like only the tags to be fixed.
I'd also like to calculate the distance between each reader and tag, i.e each reader will have 10 distances. I'm not sure how to do this and would appreciate any code to carry this out with an explanation. My code is below;

```
% 3 Readers, 10 tags at fixed positions 

A1 = 30; % area defined as 30 X 30 grid
N = 10;
R = 3; % 3 readers
s = rng; % fixed tags does not change position when simulated repatedly

% Generate x and y position of tags 
xtemp = A1*rand(1,N);
ytemp = A1*rand(1,N);
rng(s);
% Generate x and y position of points 
xtemp_2 = A1*rand(1,R);
ytemp_2 = A1*rand(1,R);

plot(xtemp,ytemp,'.',xtemp_2,ytemp_2,'rs','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',8);  
grid on
hold off
axis([0 A1 0 A1])

% Tag formatting
xoffset = 0;
yoffset = -1;
fsize = 8;
temp_str = mat2cell(num2str([xtemp(:) ytemp(:)], '(%.2f,%.2f)'), ones(1,N));
text(xtemp+xoffset, ytemp+yoffset, temp_str,'fontsize', fsize)
```

[image]

Comment: It would be much better if you showed the plot and maybe draw something manually on top of it to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In the image I'd like the black dots to remain stationary after the first execution then the red points should move around. Then I was wondering how I could calculate the distance between each red point and black one. So each red point would have 10 distances corresponding to each black one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be okay for an example.

- The random generator stops for the fixed points once generated once.
- The         `cDistance`        function returns the distances between the initially fixed points  and random points (as the column header)
- ability to recreate fixed points if we set `re_point` as 1

I encapsulated your code into a function, so we could make use of defining a `persistent` variable. This type of variable are retained in memory. The two variables in your case is `xtemp` and `ytemp` (and also the figure handle `hFig`, so we don't have to create a new figure window)

```
function TESTING (re_point)
persistent xtemp ytemp hFig
```

The variable `re_point` is a variable which you can define as 0 or 1. The default variable if run without a parameter is defined from this code. `nargin` is the number of arguments of function which is passed through

```
    if nargin<1
        re_point = 0;
    end
```

If the `persistent` variable of your fixed values, `x_temp` and `y_temp`, are already set, we don't need to set the values. Also if we had called the function `TESTING(1)`, this sets the value `re_point` as one therefore the following `if` statement is satisfied then new fixed points are generated

```
    if (isempty(xtemp) && isempty(xtemp)) || re_point == 1
        % Generate x and y position of tags 
        xtemp = A1*rand(1,N);
        ytemp = A1*rand(1,N);
    end
```

In order to label the random points, I use the `text` function to place the value of each random point as follows.

```
    for iter = 1:numel(xtemp_2)
        text(xtemp_2(iter),ytemp_2(iter), num2str(iter),...
            'FontSize',8,'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
            'Color','White','FontWeight','bold');
    end
```

There are many ways to code the calculation of the distances. I'll leave you to find more elegant ways. I used a nested function to do this. nested functions benefit from speed in most if not all situations. The downside is any nested functions are local to the parent functions. I simply ran through each fixed point and random point and used the inbuilt `pdist` MATLAB function as follows

```
    function S = distanceCalc
        S = size(numel(xtemp),numel(xtemp_2));
        for ri = 1:numel(xtemp)
            for fi = 1:numel(xtemp_2)
                S(ri,fi) = pdist([xtemp(ri),ytemp(ri);...
                            xtemp_2(fi),ytemp_2(fi)],...
                            'euclidean');
            end
        end
    end
```

---

**Here is the code in full**

```
function TESTING (re_point)
% if re_point = 0 [default]
%     points generated for xtemp and y_temp remain fixed
% if re_point = 1
%     new points are generated for x_temp and y_temp


persistent xtemp ytemp hFig
if nargin<1
    re_point = 0;
end

A1 = 30; % area defined as 30 X 30 grid
N = 10;
R = 3; % 3 readers
s = rng; % fixed tags does not change position when simulated repatedly
rng(s)

if (isempty(xtemp) && isempty(xtemp)) || re_point == 1
    % Generate x and y position of tags 
    xtemp = A1*rand(1,N);
    ytemp = A1*rand(1,N);
end
if isempty(hFig)
    hFig = figure;
end

% Generate x and y position of points 
xtemp_2 = A1*rand(1,R);
ytemp_2 = A1*rand(1,R);

% plot data
plot(xtemp,ytemp,'.',xtemp_2,ytemp_2,'rs','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',14);
for iter = 1:numel(xtemp_2)
    text(xtemp_2(iter),ytemp_2(iter), num2str(iter),...
        'FontSize',8,'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
        'Color','White','FontWeight','bold');
end
grid on
% hold off
axis([0 A1 0 A1])

% Tag formatting
xoffset = 0;
yoffset = -1;
fsize = 8;
temp_str = mat2cell(num2str([xtemp(:) ytemp(:)], '(%.2f,%.2f)'), ones(1,N));
text(xtemp+xoffset, ytemp+yoffset, temp_str,'fontsize', fsize)


cDistance = distanceCalc()

% distance function calculator
    function S = distanceCalc
        S = size(numel(xtemp),numel(xtemp_2));
        for ri = 1:numel(xtemp)
            for fi = 1:numel(xtemp_2)
                S(ri,fi) = pdist([xtemp(ri),ytemp(ri);...
                            xtemp_2(fi),ytemp_2(fi)],...
                            'euclidean');
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Could you also show what you actually changed, separately? For example, put the snippet that answers the question at the top, make a horizontal line and then put the e.g entire function below. It is very difficult to see what you did as this answer currently stands.

Comment: Thank you, this does what I want. The numbering on the red points was very helpful too. I don't understand the code though and would appreciate some comments in the code or explanations here to improve my understanding.

Comment: @Duanne I wrote some more coments. Change the function name `TESTING` to something better. Why i capitalised it I have no idea lol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not recalculate `xtemp` and `ytemp` when the script is re-run, use `exist`.

```
if ~exist('xtemp')        

    xtemp = A1*rand(1,N);
    ytemp = A1*rand(1,N);

end
```

If you want this to be stable between MATLAB sessions, save your tag points to file and tell the script to load the file if those variables aren't in the workspace already.

For the distance, if you have the Stats toolbox, look into `pdist2`. With the output of `rand` the way you have it you'll need to reorganise your data a bit:

```
% d is 10 x 3
d = pdist2([x;y]',[x2;y2]');
```

Comment: The distance works, thanks. As for the points there are two different temps; 1 and 2. The first set should be fixed, the second set generated randomly

Comment: Remove the `rng` stuff so you don't reset the random number generator, and leave the `xtemp2` stuff alone (so it is re-run every time).